# How do you convert JSON in VB.net for consumption in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, vb.net, dictionary

I was handed a php file that submits a JSON String to an API. The application I am working with to do the same, however, runs on VB.net.

I have used a Dictionary object to reconstruct the JSON object but I am getting some subtle differences in final output. Here is my code:

```
        Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

        Dim AuthDetails As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        AuthDetails.Add("UserID", 18)
        AuthDetails.Add("Token", "One")
        AuthDetails.Add("Timestamp", Date.Now().ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")

        data.Add("AuthDetails", AuthDetails)

        Dim JSONByte As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented))
        Dim JSONString As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(JSONByte).Replace(vbCrLf, "").Replace("""", """""")
```

There are two issues I am facing:

1. I have added the 2 replace methods on the JSONString because in VB.net the JSONString would have line breaks (nice formatting) and one " less than what, apparently, PHP gives out with a comparable construction. I think my code above is a fix and not a convention. But it works fine so far unless I figure out how to avoid that fix!
2. The main issue is that this is the PHP JSON String expected, which has subtle differences from what I am able to get in VB.net as show below:

PHP:

{""AuthDetails"":[{""UserID"":""18"",""Token"":""One"",""Timestamp"":""20190424132431""}]}

VB.net:

{  ""AuthDetails"": {    ""UserID"": ""18"",    ""Token"": ""One"",    ""Timestamp"": ""20190424053345""  }}

So if you look carefully, the PHP part above has some square brackets, which I am missing in my VB.net part. I understand it is PHP way of defined arrays, but I can't figure out how to do it in VB.net with the Dictionary object that I have used.

Please help me figure out the additional square bracket to my JSON String.

**Revision**:

I am able to get to this point:

{  ""AuthDetails"": [    {      ""Key"": ""UserID"",      ""Value"": ""1581""    },    {      ""Key"": ""Token"",      ""Value"": ""4f7bbcf97b4313f8353fa06c5e3a8fb6""    },    {      ""Key"": ""Timestamp"",      ""Value"": ""20190425052154""    }  ]}

when I convert the Dictionary object to Array like this:

```
        data.Add("AuthDetails", AuthDetails.toArray())
```

But that now introduces Key names and value names into the string..., which I don't need!

Thank you!

Comment: `AuthDetails` is an `IEnumerable(Of Object)` (it can be an Array, a List). Have you considered deserializing/serializing using classes? Btw, you have too many double quotes :) All the *encoding* part is just not needed (or it will end up messing with your strings).

Comment: Square brackets in php are indexed (numbered) arrays, while curly brackets are associative arrays.  So when you see [{ it means that there is an array of associative arrays. Or, you could think of it as an array of objects. Your vb Json string is assigning an object to AuthDetails instead of an array of objects.

Comment: Hi Jimi: The php file produces all those double quotes and the service accepts it; but not when I submit it from vb.net with "less" double quotes. So I added them, which I am actually quite worried will mess up parts of my variables with strings! I am still thinking of how to deal with it. The service provider insists that is what everyone else submits so they can't tinker with it...

Comment: Hi Tim: data is a complex object with nested arrays. My post is a reduction of the whole thing. I am trying to figure it out without any success. The variables need to be sent with their names, which I can't get with arrays... I can't find how to create nested arrays with names, yet

Comment: I'ld test it with the JSON correctly serialized first. Btw, you have to remove that `Formatting.Indented`. Build a class structure that represents that JSON: you have the `RootObject` class which has one property: `Public AuthDetails As List(Of AuthDetail)` and of course the `AuthDetail` class, which has three properties: `UserID`, `Token` and `Timestamp`, which can be all of type String, if you want.

Comment: Then, just call `Dim result as String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootObject)`. Try to submit this JSON, leaving the double quotes as they are and see what happens.

Comment: I don’t know vb, so I won’t be much more help. I think you’re on the right track with converting AuthDetails to an array, but I don’t understand why vb would think it needs to add a key and value... the key is the simply a count (index) and the value is the objects you add to it.  Perhaps you need to specifically assign the values when you define the array?  No clue... good luck with it

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the comments! It added up to what I have now figured out as my solution as below:

```
        Dim auth(0) As Object
        auth(0) = AuthDetails
        data.Add("AuthDetails", auth)
```

So, instead of adding AuthDetails to the data object, I added it to a defined array first (Tim Morton!).

Revision:
(Jimi) I changed the Formatting to `Formatting.None` and it removed the line breaks and also removed the need to add additional double quotes!

[Deleted the earlier comment about PHP]

Comment: Been way too long since I’ve done anything with vb, but glad you could translate what I was saying. Congrats